# Compare FDR adjustment in frequentist and Bayesian settings

Tags: bayesian, multiple-comparisons, frequentist, false-discovery-rate

Say I would like to compare two large-scale regression analyses, one in a frequentist framework (producing t-statistics or p-values) and the other in a Bayesian framework (producing marginal posterior probabilities of inclusion, MPPI).

My question is the following: do you have an idea of a false discovery rate procedure that can be applied to either p-values or MPPI so that the two analyses are comparable? I want to avoid as much as possible being overly conservative in one case compared to the other case...

Or if no such FDR procedure exists, what pair of multiple testing methods do you think would be best to use so that the corrections are more or less comparable?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].